# Proof Surjective function with no ''given'' function

Tags: functions, real-numbers

$f_1 : \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f_2 : \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$  and define $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ as $f(x,y) = (f_1(x,y),f_2(x,y))$.

> Question: If $f$ is surjective. Proof that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are also surjective.

So what I thought was that if $f$ is surjective, this means that for all $b$ (element of $\mathbb{R}^2$) there exists an $a$ (element of $\mathbb{R}^2$) so that $f(a)=b$. However, I don't know how to continue this proof without having a function as I can't find an inverse function.

I would like some help. Thanks !

Comment: Surjective just means that the range is the whole space.

Comment: A side comment as to one motivation behind this kind of question: There is a common game in mathematics, which is "How little do I have to know about a thing before I can say something about it?" So they're not going to tell me exactly what $f_1$ and $f_2$ are? Fine, but they tell me that they both participate in the given way in $f$, and $f$ is surjective. Is that enough to tell me that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are also surjective? It is. It turns out you *don't* have to know exactly what they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $x$ in $\Bbb R$; you want to prove that there is some $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$ such that $f_1(a,b)=x$. Since $f$ is surjective, there is some $(a,b)\in\Bbb R^2$ such that $f(a,b)=(x,0)$. But then $f_1(a,b)=x$. This proves that $f_1$ is surjective.

By the same argument, $f_2$ is surjective.

Comment: You are right: you cannot deduce from the fact that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are surjective that $f$ is surjective.

Comment: Yes: if $f_1(x,y)=f_2(x,y)=x$, then$$\operatorname{range}(f)=\{(Z,Z)\mid Z\in\Bbb R\}\varsubsetneq\Bbb R^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Projections $\pi_1,\pi_2:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ are surjective and composition of surjective maps (like $f_1=\pi_1\circ f$ and $f_2=\pi_2\circ f$) is still surjective, hence the conclusion.